# Simple add more field using AHAH in custom form in Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal-6, ahah

I have a custom form (call from menu hook) as below :

`$items['testform'] = array(
    'title' => 'testform',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => 'test_form',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
);`

Now in this form built with Drupal 6 Form API, I want to add "Add More" field using AHAH.

Can anyone give me ideas how do I?

Answer (score 0):

AHAH is quite complicated in Drupal 6. You will need custom submit and AHAH callback functions, as well as adding the AHAH element to the form.

Have a read of https://www.drupal.org/node/331941 and http://katbailey.net/blog/ahah-drupal-may-it-one-day-live-its-acronym?quicktabs_9=1.